# asd scroller - how to pause on hover JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple scroller for ads ;]
Need help whit pause it on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function(mnmTicker){
  var mnmAdsInterval = 2000;
/* Do not modify code below */
var mnmAdsLenght = m3ads_numberadverts;
function mnmSlideAds(){
    hT = $('.someClass').find('a');
    hT2 = hT;
    slideMargin = document.getElementsByClassName('a')[0].offsetHeight;
    $(".someClass .a:first").clone().appendTo(".someClass");
    $(".someClass .a:first").animate({"marginTop":-+slideMargin,},1800, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

  };
  var interval = setInterval(mnmSlideAds, mnmAdsInterval); [/code]
```

BTW. Im testing this:

```
$('.someClass .a').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, function() {
        interval = setInterval(mnmSlideAds, mnmAdsInterval); 
    });
```

but do not work ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You disabling only interval, but need to [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) animations too:

```
$('.someClass .a').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $(".someClass .a:first").stop();
}, function() {
    interval = setInterval(mnmSlideAds, mnmAdsInterval); 
});
```

Comment: Thx, but when testing it's don't stop ;/